# Request from public IP on the same network very slow nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, networking

I'm currently an annoying issue where if i go to http://{myipdomain} from the same network  with the same public address, the responses will be very very slow or almost non-existent because the page load indefinitely.
But, if i connect with another IP, with a VPN or cellular phone, the responses will be normal and very quick.
Why does that happen?

nginx config

```
server {

    server_name _;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000; 
        # On same network, responses is very slow but with another ip, responses is fast
    }

}
```

NodeJS code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello World!</h1>')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port: ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: probably dns backresolv

Comment: @yvs2014 Can you give me more details please?

Comment: it's just a guess. To check it out: on host with nginx in CLI try to type `host ipaddress` (ipaddress of your computer)